# How to make the brush with the side of an even size (GIMP)?

Tags: gimp, brush

I created a brush in the GIMP that is in the shape of a square.

I created the same so I could draw mazes for a game I'm doing. It turns out that the width of my maze is 10 pixels and I can not make the brush 10x10.

[image]

You should be able to make the brush stick with the even side, if there is no one would like to know why.

**LINKS IN PORTUGUESE (BRAZIL)**

I searched here => https://docs.gimp.org/2.8/pt_BR/gimp-using-variable-size-brush.html

Also here => https://docs.gimp.org/2.8/pt_BR/gimp-brush-dialog.html

But without success... If neither the GIMP website itself helped me what else could I do?

Sorry for the translation errors, I'm not an English speaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, both the "VBR" brushes and the sizing slider used for paint tools is not too apropriate to have a fixed size brush with this accuracy. The way to do it is really create a 10x10pixel image, convert it to grayscale, paint it black, and export it as a  `.gbr` file to one of GIMP's brush folders (which you can find, or create a new one at `edit->preferences->folders->brushes`)

However, I would not recommend the approach you are taking for what you want to achieve - as GIMP's grid system which would allow you to actually paint at 10px round coordinates is a bit "soft" in its snapping, and you would ed up doing a lot of undo/redo -

The most practial way to draw a maze with square block walls is:

- create an image 10 times smaller than the desired one.
- Use the  `pencil` tool, and set the brush (almost any brush will do) size to "1" on the tool options dialog. Don't even worry about the original brush size.
- Draw your maze working at 1000% (or larger) zoom factor.
- When maze is done, enlarge image, setting interpolation to None to prevent pixel blurring: `Image->Scale Image...`, type "1000%" on the width field, and let GIMP calculate the final image size, and change the `Interpolation` to `None` on the "Quality" drop down.
- Export your image, and proceed to draw details smaller than 10px, if any.

Comment: Well, now an error occurs when I use the shift to make the lines. The line does not start from where I clicked, it starts lower and it does not stay straight.

Comment: His idea of ​​drawing the mazes 10 times smaller is really tempting.

Comment: From what I noticed (returning to my new problem) is that the center of the brush is not being selected correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If you want accuracy, I suggest you make a GIMP .gbr brush.

1. Create a new image 10px x 10px, fill it with black. Set the colour mode to grayscale, and make sure there is no alpha channel on the background layer.
2. Export the image as *square.gbr* (or whatever file name you want), and put it in your GIMP brushes folder.
3. Refresh the brushes panel in GIMP
4. Select the Pencil Tool, choose the brush you made, and set the size to 10

Here's a screenshot

[image]

Comment: Well, now an error occurs when I use the shift to make the lines. The line does not start from where I clicked, it starts lower and it does not stay straight.

Comment: From what I noticed (returning to my new problem) is that the center of the brush is not being selected correctly.

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso I'm sorry, I don't know what your problem is. What you describe doesn't make sense to me because I can't see what you are actually trying to do. Your question was how to make a 10px brush, and I answered that. If you have another question then better to ask a new one